# '.symfix+' is not recognized on cmd terminal

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, debug-symbols

I am trying to follow [this WinDBG tutorial](http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2013/12/getting-started-with-windbg-part-1.html), and at some point, it requires the [Microsoft public symbol server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/microsoft-public-symbols) to be set up. I ran the command:

```
set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv*DownstreamStore*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

followed by

```
.symfix+ C:\MySymbols
```

but I get the infamous error message

> '.symfix+' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

My environment, running the command `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"` is:

- OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
- OS Version:                10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Comment: `.symfix` is a command of WinDbg. Using it outside of WinDbg is as meaningless as talking Chinese to an Englishman.

Comment: @IInspectable aha, that `dbgcmd` means that command needs to be run in the WinDbg. I'm so novice that no one ever had made such a mistake before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=...
```

sets an environment variable that attempts to tell all debugging programs where to download symbols. This affects WinDbg, Visual Studio, Process Explorer and others.

The command

```
.symfix
```

is WinDbg specific and is an equivalent to the above. Setting both is not necessary.

Please note that you should not enter this part

```
srv*DownstreamStore*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

literally. You should replace the part `DownstreamStore` by a place where you want the downloaded symbols to be stored on your hard disk. So in your case, this should be `C:\MySymbols`.

The command `.symfix` just takes `DownstreamStore` as an argument and puts `srv*` before and `*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` after that argument. So using

```
.symfix C:\MySymbols
```

is equivalent to

```
.sympath srv*C:\MySymbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

but much easier to type.

The `+` in these commands (`.sympath+` or `.symfix+`) will *append* another symbol path, assuming that you already had one set up before.

Neither `set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH` nor `.symfix` nor `.sympath` will actually download symbols. The symbols will be downloaded on demand. Use `ld*; reload /f` when being attached to a process for downloading symbols.

Or, as mentioned by yourself, use the command line tool [`symchk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-symchk).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, the `.symfix` command is a WinDbg one, which needs to be entered at the software's command line, not the Windows terminal cmd!

However, there are certain command-line tools that can do the job, partly! The complete "WinDbg Command-Line Options" documentation can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/windbg-command-line-options). Also, there is the [`symchk` tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-symchk) coming with the "[Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk)". One can download the "Microsoft's public symbol" database using the command:

```
symchk "path\to\binary" /s srv*DownstreamStore*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

**P.S.** Usefull [common WinDbg commands](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html)